# Image of $f: A\to B$, $\;f(x)=|x/2|$, for $x\in \mathbb Q$ such that $-12\leq x\leq 4$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}, B \subset \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{0\}$, and $A=\{{x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid -12\leq x \leq4}\}.\;$ Find $f(A)$, where $f(x)= |\frac x2|$.

How to start? $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers, so in $A$ will be $1/2,1/3,1/4$... to $4$ and in the negative to $-12$? There will be a lot of numbers to write! Please help.

Is it $$A=\{−12,−11,−10,−9,−8,−7,−6,−5,−4,−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3,4\}$$ or no?

Comment: Is the set $B$ used at all?

Comment: Yes there is one more request $f^{-1}(B)$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the image of $f$ is
$$\{|x/2|:x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[-12,4]\}.$$
I think it will be easier to see what this reduces to if you notice that
\begin{align}
\{|x/2|:x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[-12,4]\}&= \{x/2:x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,12]\}
\end{align}
This is because $f(x)=\left|x/2\right| \geq 0, \forall x \in \mathbb Q\cap [-12, 4]$, so we can just assume we're working on a set of non-negative numbers, and then the absolute value bars aren't needed.

I claim that
$$\{x/2:x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,12]\}= \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,6].$$
To show these sets are equal, observe that the left-hand-side is clearly contained in the RHS because if we take a rational number in $[0,12]$ and divide it by $2$, it is now in $[0,6]$ and still rational. Conversely, given any rational number $q\in[0,6]$, $2q$ is a rational number in $[0,12]$ and $q=2q/2$. Therefore the image of $f$ is the set of rational numbers between $0$ and $6$. Hence,
$$f(A)=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,6]$$

Comment: Tell me is it $A=\{{-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1,2,3,4\}}$ or no?

Comment: No, $A$ is every rational number between $-12$ and $4$. You only listed the integers in that range. You can't possibly write down all the rationals since there are infinitely many of them, which is why we use set notation

Comment: Indeed, Viktor, please read through this answer carefully:  In your own statement of the problem, Viktor, we have $xA = \{x\in \mathbb Q\mid -12\leq x\leq 4\}$.  That means $A$ contains all rational numbers in the interval $[-12, 4] \subset \mathbb Q$.  While $A$ does contain the intergers you list, $A$ contains countably infinite many of rational numbers, of which there are only finitely many integers.  Note that $f(A) = \{ |x/2|\mid x\in \mathbb Q \cap [-12, 4]\}$, and @pwerth helps you to narrow that down.